# Send URL scheme in an email

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, url-scheme

I have implemented a url scheme in my app. I am successfully able to launch my app from safari. Now the requirement is that i need to send some kind of url to the user in an email, on clicking that url my app will be launched. Now i read somewhere that we can append our url scheme in the email body, user can open that email in his Mail.app from his device and use our app. Can someone give me an exact example of adding the url scheme to the email, i am not able to correctly send the url scheme to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheme is the same as in HTML, thus just add `my-app://` to the mail. 
If the mail is HTMl just us it it like: `<a href="my=app://">Launch</a>`.

Only be aware that if the user does not have your app installed nothing will happen.

Comment: Do i need to send the email from code? I am not able to get this working from gmail's web interface.

Comment: Well I just send a mail via Gmail's webinterface, added al link with add link button and was able to open my app on my iPhone with that link in the e-mail.